# How do you get code of a clisp memory image

Tags: common-lisp, clisp

I have got a memory image, that i can't find the source for and I want to get the code out of it again. What do i have to do to achieve that? I can obviously load the image, but then i'd need to guess the function names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get "interesting" symbols with (apropos ""), and the function names with `WITH-PACKAGE-ITERATOR` and `FBOUNDP`. But the source code is (probably) lost: try DISASSEMBLE on functions and see the information which *is* there.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [`DISASSEMBLE`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_disass.htm), you might try [`EXT:UNCOMPILE`](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/debugger.html#uncompile). Note, however, that it will only work on functions compiled in an interactive session (i.e., from REPL), not on those loaded from a compiled `.fas` file.

So, the suggested procedure is:

1. [`LIST-ALL-PACKAGES`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_list_a.htm) - figure out which packages are interesting.
2. [`DO-EXTERNAL-SYMBOLS`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_do_sym.htm) - figure out which symbols in the interesting packages are interesting.
3. `DISASSEMBLE` or `EXT:UNCOMPILE` on those interesting symbols.

However, the easiest way is to contact your vendor. Remember, [CLISP is distributed under the GNU GPL](http://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/clisp/ci/default/tree/COPYRIGHT).